# Filtering in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

In my project I use django rest framework. To filter the results I use django_filters backend.
There is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)


class Town(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False')
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters
from models import Town


class TownFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    region = django_filters.CharFilter(name="region__name", lookup_type="contains")
    town = django_filters.CharFilter(name="name", lookup_type="contains")

    class Meta:
        model = Town
        fields = ['region', 'town']
```

**views.py**

```
from models import Town
from rest_framework import generics
from serializers import TownSerializer
from filters import TownFilter


class TownList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Town.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TownSerializer
    filter_class = TownFilter
```

So, I can write **?region=Region_name&town=Town_name** to the end of the request url, and the result will be filtered.

But I want to use only one get param in the request url, which can have **region** or **town name** as value. For example **?search=Region_name** and **?search=Town_name**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options, but the easiest way is to just override 'get_queryset' in your API view.

Example from the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering) adapted to your use case:

```
class TownList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Town.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TownSerializer
    filter_class = TownFilter(generics.ListAPIView)
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Town.objects.all()
        search_param = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('search', None)
        if search_param is not None:
            """
            set queryset here or use your TownFilter 
            """
        return queryset
```

Another way is to set your `search_fields` on the list api view class in combination use the `SearchFilter` class. The problem is that if you're filtering over multiple models, you may have to do some additional implementation here to make sure it's looking at exactly what you want. If you're not doing anything fancy, just put double underscores for region for example: `region__name`

Comment: Thanks, but I gave a simplified example of my code in question. The Town model have more then two fields. And all this fields I want to use in filter. For example, url may have ?search=Region/Town&param1=...&param2=... That's why your solution is not so good for me

Comment: I don't understand why using a SearchFilter or simply overriding queryset doesn't accomplish exactly that. I can't know what your intention is because you didn't ask that in your question, rather you just asked for 1 search param. Just add a second self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('param1', None) for example. Then return the queryset. Alternatively, just do that in the SearchFilter.

Comment: I have 25 fields in model, which I want to use in filter. And only town and region fields should be together in search GET var in the url. 'search_fields' works only with one GET var. And if I will override 'get_queryset', then I should write QUERY_PARAMS.get('param1', None) 23 times.

Comment: So please reword your question, this isn't what you asked at all. 
Why do you want to filter across 25 fields? I would ask myself first - maybe you have a good reason. It is usually a really bad idea though because you typically would not have 25 covering indices for those fields, i.e. it will run horribly slow one would expect. If you really do need 25 fields, be a programmer and simply write a simple function that matches the query param to the field (easy if it's 1:1, otherwise create a dict) and constructs the query. This is a classic builder pattern.

Comment: Also please read the docs in my answer. It explicitly states, "Note that you can use both an overridden .get_queryset() and generic filtering together, and everything will work as expected." In other words, again, I don't see how it will give you a problem. I don't have your code to write for you, so it's up to you.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is a way to filter on both column and global filtering. Column filtering is done via ?column_name=value and the global filtering is done via ?search=any_text

Answer (score 0):

With [dj-rest-filters](https://dj-rest-filters.readthedocs.io/), you can write your filters with similar syntax as of serializer. For your case, it will be like this

```
from djfilters import filters

class MyFilter(filters.Filter):
    search = filters.CharField()
    
    def filter_search(self, qs, value):
        qs = qs.filter(#Your filter logic here)
        return qs
```