# Simple Filter in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models: author and comment. I need to get list of comments filtered by author_id! Something like this:

1. *api/authors/**author_id**/comments*
2. or this: *api/comments?author_id=**author_id***
3. or this: *api/comments/author/**author_id***

Here is official docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering

Here is similar question: [Filtering in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662597/filtering-in-django-rest-framework)

It doesn't help me. Unfortunately, there are no full simple examples for this task in internet.

Please tell me, what should I change in my code to do this filtering?

My code:

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='author_comments')
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```py
# serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from core.models import Author, Comment

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from models import  Author, Comment
from serializers import AuthorSerializer, CommentSerializer

class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
```

```py
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'comments', views.CommentViewSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DRF-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/drf-extensions/)** has a feature called *[Nested routes](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes)* that allows you to append route logic to `ViewSets` (which is your case). It looks like what you want and the simplest.

Comment: It's great to include citations in your answer, however it would improve it greatly if you included the part of the example that you feel would best help answer the question.  That way if the links break in the future, the relevant information is still here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create filtered query set. here in this example i have filtered comments by author id

**views.py**

```
class CommentFilter(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the comments for
        particular author by author portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['author_id']
        return Comment.objects.filter(author__id=author_id)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'comments', views.CommentViewSet)
router.register(r'comment_list/(?P<author_id>\d+)/?$', views.CommentFilter,base_name="comment_list")
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Where should I add this code (what file should I use)? Should I change something in urls.py or other files?

if I add this class to view, and use it the urls.py  — I get an error:
_AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute._

Comment: I get an error: 
**AssertionError: base_name argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a .queryset attribute**

Comment: router.register(r'comment_list/(?P<author_id>\d+)/?$', views.CommentFilter base_name="comment_list")

Comment: Another error: **view = viewset.as_view(mapping, **route.initkwargs)
TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Comment: Try views.CommentFilter.as_view()

Comment: Already tried... doesn't helped...
Finally I've found another solution, I will write it here later... anyway thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Nested URLs are unnecessarily difficult in DRF. As the issue that you linked hints, it's simplest to just extract a query parameter:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Club.objects.all()
        author_id = self.request.query_params.get('author_id')

        if author_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(author_id=author_id)
        return queryset
```

You'd use this like your option 2 above:

`api/comments?author_id=author_id`

Comment: This will work but you need to use a generics.ListAPIView instead of a viewset.